# Why can we get probability of two integers being coprime while there is no uniform distribution on integers?

Tags: probability, number-theory

I know the coprime probability is about $1/\zeta(2)=6/\pi^2$. However, we can not define uniform distribution on $Z^+\times Z^+$, so how do we **define** the coprime probability?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is really measured here is the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) (or asymptotic density). To be more precise, we define the natural density of a subset $S \subseteq {\mathbb{N}}^2$ as the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{|S_n|}{n^2}$ where $S_n = \{(x, y) \in S: 1 \leq x, y \leq n\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered in a comment: $\frac6{\pi^2}$ is the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of pairs of coprime integers in $\mathbb N^2$, defined by

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{(x,y)\in\mathbb N^2:1\le x,y\le n\land \gcd(x,y)=1\}|}{n^2}\;.
$$